# Replace an image after a certain number of page loads?

Tags: php, image

How should I replace an image after a set number of page loads?

I have a folder of images (could be numbered consecutively or have something appended on upload) and after X number of page loads by any user the image changes, and this just continues through the images in the folder with the idea that more get added over time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On each page load you can a value to a db field (example) or a file (example2), then when you load you check this value before showing the image.

Comment: Asking for _the best way_ will most likely attract opinionated answers. Such questions are off-topic for SO. Morevore, you should provide your approach on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase a counter in a database, each time the page is loaded. 
Then depending on that counter, display an image, e.g.:

```
imageIndex = (numberOfPageVisits / changeImageAfterSoManyVisits) % numberOfImages
```

Answer (score 0):

One method could be setting a cookie to count the times the user has accessed the website and once it hits a certain amount, then the new image shows and the counter sets back down to 0.

Something along these lines:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['load_counter'])) {
    // Create cookie for counter
    $cookie_value = "0";
    setcookie("load_counter", $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day * 30 = 30 days
} else if($_COOKIE['load_counter'] < 5) { 
    // update cookie if its less than the 5th hit
    $cookie_val = $_COOKIE['load_counter'] + 1;
    setcookie("load_counter", $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day * 30 = 30 days
} else {
    // RUN NEW IMAGE HERE

    // Reset counter
    $cookie_value = "0";
    setcookie("load_counter", $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day * 30 = 30 days
}
```

No need for any database connections then, very little overhead for the server and will be exceptionally quick on the front end.

Comment: This means views by one client do not count towards views by other clients - not sure whether OP meant that, as he says "by any user" rather than "by any particular user".

Comment: True, there isn't a great of explanation in how this is meant to be run. From previous experience, i have always tried to run it on a user by user basis as this reduces load on the server and removes the risk of people trying to do naughty things to the database (XSS). If it is on a user by user basis, then i would personally just randomise it on each load because who's really going to notice/care.

Comment: Yes - the idea is that the "count" is any user, not a particular user.

Comment: Ill add to my answer in a minute, will just put something together.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

// get the images from the db
mysql_select_db($database_Database, $Database);
$query_rs_images = "SELECT * FROM image_degrade WHERE counter > 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$rs_images = mysql_query($query_rs_images, $Database) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_images);
$totalRows_rs_images = mysql_num_rows($rs_images);

$file = "images/gallery/" . $row_rs_images['filename'];

// resave the image at reduced quality
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($file), $file, $row_rs_images['counter']);

// reduce the quality var by 1
$row_rs_images['counter'] = $row_rs_images['counter'] - 1;

// update the db
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE image_degrade SET `counter`=%s WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($row_rs_images['counter'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($row_rs_images['id'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_Database, $Database);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $Database) or die(mysql_error());

// output the image
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($file);

mysql_free_result($rs_images);
?>
```